# What is the difference between an ObjectDisposedException and a SocketException

Tags: c#, sockets

I've already looked up the definitions and all but since I am dealing with server code I wanna know EXACTLY what is going on here.

So the way I'm interpreting it so far is that a SocketException happens if something outside of the program happens to the socket; such as, the network going down or the client closing the connection on his end.  Meaning I have to call shutdown and close on my end?  Is this how I'm supposed to detect that a client shuts down the connection?  When an exception is thrown?

The way I'm interpreting the ObjectDisposedException is that it occurs when I called shutdown and close on that socket from another thread or something and I am still using the dead socket somewhere else.

Comment: I think the exception names are very indicative

Comment: You might also need to check the documentation for whatever method is *throwing* these exceptions. The MSDN documentation will usually indicate what exceptions a method may throw and can often give more detail of the reasons why *that* method may choose one exception over another.

Comment: Getting ODE in the callback method for a BeginReceive() call is quite normal.  It indicates that the call didn't succeed, because you closed the socket, you should always catch it and immediately return.